# Extjs window is skewed after destoy

Tags: javascript, extjs, window

if you follow this wizard http://jsfiddle.net/8tBKa/ you will see that.
button 1 open a window.
button 2 destroy it.
button 3 recreate the window.

after the recreation, the window is skewed.

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.window.Window",
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {              
        xtype: 'form',
        itemId: "Window",
        defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 150,
            columnWidth: .33,
            padding: "10px 30x 10px 10px"
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'column',
            columns: 3,
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width: 100,
            fieldLabel: "Some input"
        }
    })

});

var win = false;
function show(){
    win = Ext.create("MyWindow");
    win.show();
}
function close(){
    win.close();
}

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        title : "Panel",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {xtype : "button", text : "Step 1 (Create window)", handler : show },
            {xtype : "button", text : "Step 2 (Destroy window)", handler : close },
            {xtype : "button", text : "Step 3 (Create NEW window)", handler : show }
        ],
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for the info, but, if I want to access the form from the window constructor, I actually cant.
If add the following function to the window:

```
constructor: function () {
    this.items[0].getForm().load({/*bla bla*/});
    this.callParent();
}
```

I will get an error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getForm'`
(http://jsfiddle.net/8tBKa/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue lies with the create statement within the window for the form.  Changing this got me the desired result:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.window.Window",
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{              
        xtype: 'form',
        itemId: "Window",
        defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 150,
            columnWidth: .33,
            padding: "10px 30x 10px 10px"
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'column',
            columns: 3,
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width: 100,
            fieldLabel: "Some input"
        }
    }]

});
```

In regards to **update 1**:  Would you be able to add the constructor instead to the form?

(modifications to the init and added render listener to the window)

Because the form was not rendered yet, getForm() was undefined. I ended up adding listener to render in window to fulfill requirements of completion in window. Working fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dTKPy/)

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.window.Window",
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    layout: 'fit',
    listeners:{
        render:function(win){
            console.log('getting here');
            win.down('form').getForm().load({"url":"hello"});
        }
    },
    items: [{              
        xtype: 'form',
        itemId: "Window",
        defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 150,
            columnWidth: .33,
            padding: "10px 30x 10px 10px"
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'column',
            columns: 3,
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width: 100,
            fieldLabel: "Some input",
            name:'url'
        }
    }]

});
```

Comment: thanks, I know that, can you please read UPDATE 1 on my question? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your solution is not working (http://jsfiddle.net/8tBKa/3/) and not exactly what I need. I want to access the form from the window and not from the form itself, Thanks....

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it needed to be initComponent, however, this wouldn't work anyway because the form isn't rendered yet.  Added listener to render in the window in solution and added fiddle

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Ext.create when you're defining the class. It means the form instance will be shared between window instances. So once the window is destroyed, so is the form and it remains with the window.

Instead, just use a configuration with the `xtype` attached.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. it is not yet solved, I cant access the form from the window.

Comment: Of course you can't, you didn't call the superclass constructor yet.

Comment: If you mean switch the rows on the constructor, it does not work, can you pls fix it on the jsfiddle? thanks